# Pivot table on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I'm trying to make a table pivot on a postgresql database but i can't succeed.
Here is my original request

```
SELECT tag_country.label, COUNT(*)
FROM log_event_tracking LEFT JOIN user_account ON log_event_tracking.email = user_account.email LEFT JOIN tag_country ON user_account.country = tag_country.id
WHERE date_time > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY tag_country.label;
```

and here is the result

| label | count |
| --- | --- |
| <null> | 50 |
| Spain | 23 |
| France | 99 |

What i'm trying to do is to pivot this table to get this result

| <null> | Spain | France |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 23 | 99 |

Does anyone have a solution ?
Thanks for your answers.

EDIT :

Forgot to say that i might have more countries or less countries depending of the database i'm requesting and i need it works with the same query

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function  crosstab from tablefunc extention, I'll put an exemple here to use it.

Here you'll need create the tablefunc extention if not exists

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

CREATE TABLE exams (
     id bigserial NOT NULL,
     name text,
     exam int,
     score int,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Bob',1,70);
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Bob',2,77); 
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Bob',3,71);
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Bob',4,70);

insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Sue',1,89);
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Sue',2,87);
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Sue',3,88);
insert into exams (name,exam,score) values ('Sue',4,89);
```

Now you can run your query converting it to a pivot table, the result you can see on the attached picture.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('select name, exam, score from exams order by 1,2')
         AS ct (name text,exam1 int, exam2 int, exam3 int, exam4 int);
```

[image: result for pivot table]

I hope this can help you man.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it's exactly what i'm trying to do. There is just one thing different : i'm trying to do it with a dynamic number of exam.
Is there a way to indicate to crosstab that there is (name text, exams... int) or something like that

Comment: Hello @BenoitBonavia , can you share your query or tables model to crarify better my understanding?

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you are after with SQL. However I suggest what you asking is not a very good idea, it involve way to much maintenance just to keep the query accurate without any other benefit. But first, how to do it. Well the `tablefunc` suggestion will work, another option is the Postgres `filter` clause.

```
select "<null>", "France", "Spain"
  from ( 
        select count(*) filter (where label is null) as "<null>"
             , count(*) filter (where label = 'France') as "France"
             , count(*) filter (where label = 'Spain')  as "Spain"
          from tag_country             
       ) sq;
```

The problem with both of them being you **must know the exact pivot columns** before running the query and update when modifications are made. Thus if you *have more countries or less countries depending of the database I'm requesting and i need it works with the same query*, cannot be realized. Your options are updating the query or writing an involved process to generate the SQL on the fly :( or pushing the pivoting off to the presentation layer in application. The query becomes a simple counting:

```
select label, count(*)
  from tag_country 
 group by label
 order by label nulls first;
```

SQL excels at slicing any dicing the data, but is very poor at formatting the results. Your presentation manager just needs to shift the vertical result set into a horizontal one. At which it should excel.  

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f3625ca58cc508336cfd7ba476c7008c);